# Use templates to generate pure virtual base class methods

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, pure-virtual

That may sound kind of strange, and I may have to refactor my code at some point but I would need to generate the pure virtual base class methods with a template function. Is it doable with C++11 (variadic templates ?) ?

Example :

```
struct I
{
    virtual void foo(int) = 0;
    virtual void foo(float) = 0;
};

struct S : public I
{
    template<typename T>
    void foo(T t) { /*do the same symbolic stuff on t*/ } 
};

int main()
{
    S s;
    s.foo(0);
    s.foo(0.0f);
    return 0;
}
```

Giving the following error (clang) :

```
main.cpp:65:7: error: variable type 'S' is an abstract class
    S s;
      ^
main.cpp:53:18: note: unimplemented pure virtual method 'foo' in 'S'
    virtual void foo(int) = 0;
                 ^
main.cpp:54:18: note: unimplemented pure virtual method 'foo' in 'S'
    virtual void foo(float) = 0;
                 ^
1 error generated.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do that.

A signature of a template method is not the same of a non-template method.

And you can't have a virtual template method.

Comment: Ah, thanks for pointing the problem with virtual...I thought you could always override a pure virtual method with a final one, so you can't ?

Comment: You can, but not with a template. void foo(int) is not equivalent to void foo<T>(T) no matter how you read it... The template becomes part of the method name.

Comment: Yes is not equivalent...but I would have imagined the compiler look at the base class and try to implement the template specialization of foo...sadly this is not the case...Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do it directly, but you can use forwarders to have a common implementation:

```
struct S : public I
{
private:
    template<typename T>
    void foo_impl(T t) { /*do the same symbolic stuff on t*/ } 
public:
    virtual void foo(int v) { foo_impl(v); }
    virtual void foo(float v) { foo_impl(v); }
};
```

Comment: Thanks, but you still have to implement the virtual methods with the same symbolic stuff even though factored... :/

Comment: @matovitch If you're particularly masochistic you can also do this with a CRTP, assuming there are multiple `S` that may be doing the same thing, it may be worth considering, as it alleviates wheel-reinvention more than once.

Comment: @matovitch Sure, but they are simple one-liners, while `foo_impl` might be more complex and hence you still improved maintainability, avoiding future errors when refactoring.

Comment: @WhozCraig Can you elaborate please...CRTP is the trick of passing the derived class as template parameter of the base class isnt it ? Maybe you should answer ? ;)

Comment: @matovitch you pretty much hit, and it sounds like you understand. Its the same premise as this answer (provide an implementation that invokes your template while fulfilling the pure base in the process). But that implementation can be in a CRTP base derived from `I`, which `S` and any other class you wish, can base from. [Something like this](http://ideone.com/RVJqY2). At least then you only have to implement the actual call-fowarding once for all derivations, so long as they implement a proper `foo_impl` template member.